# How can I run multiple test runner classes using gradle command line

Tags: testing, gradle, automation

I have test runner classes that are dynamically generated by gradle tasks. How can I run multiple test runner classes using gradle command line?

For example:

I have these test runners:

```
T1: ssbhxxxTestRunner
T2: ssbheeeTestRunner
T3: ssbheeeTestRunner
T4: ssbhnewTestRunner
T5: ssbhnewTestRunner
```

I now need a grade command to include all the testRunners except `T2`. I used:

`gradle clean test -Dtest.single=ssbh^((?!hede).)*TestRunner`

however gradle doesn't seem to support this type of regex, and my tests do not run.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the TestFilter https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html 
and do it with a property that you then can set.
Example

```
test {
   filter {
      if (hasProperty('filterProp'))
        includeTestsMatching filterProp
    }
 }
```

Call it now with

```
gradle clean test -P filterProp='ssbh^((?!hede).)*TestRunner'
```